# SettingWithCopyWarning for no apparent reason when converting timeStamp to pandas daytime

Tags: pandas

I run the following line to convert integer timestamp to daytime object for my dataFrame:

```
df.loc[:, 'timeStamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'timeStamp'], unit='ms')
```

This causes getting `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning, I don't get why as I am using `.loc` to set values. The changes appear to be successful. Is it me, or something with `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: Why do you use the loc at the beginning, loc I think creates a view on the original dataframe as I can recall, and it is having a hard time deciding what you want to do, change the original dataframe... - Acutally it creates a standalone series - corrected

Comment: Well I am trying to change original DataFrame not it's copy, I've read that when you want to change something in dataFrame you should use .loc.

Comment: Can you try without the loc and the :, ? It should not complain then...
just df['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms')

Comment: It still gives the warning. I also tried df.loc[:, 'timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms') with the same result.

Comment: is df a result of another loc?

Comment: if it is - when creating df try to put a .copy() at the end. Eg.: 
first_df = pd.read_csv(file)
df = first_df.loc[first_df.col > 5]
then when you want to change it, it starts complaining... because the derived frame is a view... probably your original frame is a view...
to suppress it you can do:
df = first_df[df.col > 5].copy()
then df is a real dataframe...

Comment: Thanks that's it, I should have thought of that.